# Как искать изображение в определенной области pyautogui

Tags: python, pyautogui

Не понимаю что надо вписать в region, мне нужно искать изображение примерно в центре экрана

```
import pyautogui

while True:
    cord_a = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('test.png',region = (), confidence=0.5)
    if cord_a == None:
        pass
    else:
        pyautogui.moveTo(cord_a)
        print(cord_a)
```